# Creating a loop in functions.php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am trying to create a loop that will work as a custom navigation menu in the header using custom post type manager. I am creating a function in the functions.php and then calling the function in the header.php. I can't use the regular " while : have posts etc.." because it actually changes the page content. I just want to create a function that will bring up the image, custom fields, etc..

Here is my code that doesn't work:

```
 <?php
    // Our Team Navigation Menu

    function our_team_arg( $arg2 ) {

    $arg2 = array('posts_per_page' => 60, 'post_type' => 'our_team');

       query_posts($arg2);

    $myposts = get_posts( $arg2 );

    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );  
    ?>
     <div class="founderblk">
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
           <img alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" src="<?php print_custom_field('team_member_image:to_image_src'); ?>">
       </a><br />
      <span class="foundertitle"><?php print_custom_field('team_member_title'); ?></span>
     </div>
  <?php
  endforeach; 

    wp_reset_postdata();
 }
   // END Our Team Navigation Menu
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use wp_query and use while normally it will not change the page content when you are using `wp_reset_postdata();`
and query_posts actually call wp_query internally
here is an example

```
 $args = array('posts_per_page' => 60, 'post_type' => 'site-product');
  // The Query
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) { 

  while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) { $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

   <div class="founderblk">
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
           <img alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" src="<?php print_custom_field('team_member_image:to_image_src'); ?>">
       </a><br />
      <span class="foundertitle"><?php print_custom_field('team_member_title'); ?></span>
     </div>
<?php 
 }

} else {
  // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

for the second line in your code

```
$arg2 = array('posts_per_page' => 60, 'post_type' => 'our_team');
```

I assume that you write it for testing because it is actually overwrite the function arguments